# load new zealand stock price from yahoo finance

Tags: r, quantmod

Noobie here guys so please be gentle :)

I am trying to load data from yahoo finance using quantmod for all NZ listed stocks. The following is what I have. But apparently the data is missing when I try to look inside. What am I doing wrong?

```
library(TTR)
library(quantmod)
install.packages("PerformanceAnalytics")
library(PerformanceAnalytics)

#Make a new environment for quantmod to store data in 
 stockData <- new.env() 

#Specify period of time we are interested in
 startDate = as.Date("2009-01-01") 
 endDate = as.Date("2014-01-30")

#Define the tickers we are interested in
 tickers <- > c("ABA.NZ","ACY.NZ","AIA.NZ","AIR.NZ","ALF.NZ","AOR.NZ","ARG.NZ","ATM.NZ","AUG.NZ","AWF.NZ","AWK.NZ","BGR.NZ","BLT.NZ","BRL.NZ","BRM.NZ","CAV.NZ","CDI.NZ","CEN.NZ","CMO.NZ","CNU.NZ","CVT.NZ","DGL.NZ","DIL.NZ","DNZ.NZ","DPC.NZ","EBO.NZ","FBU.NZ","FIN.NZ","FPH.NZ","FRE.NZ","FSF.NZ","GMT.NZ","GXH.NZ","HBY.NZ","HLG.NZ","HNZ.NZ","IFT.NZ","KFL.NZ","KIP.NZ","KMD.NZ","KRK.NZ","LPC.NZ","MCK.NZ","MELCA.NZ","MET.NZ","MFT.NZ","MGL.NZ","MHI.NZ","MLN.NZ","MOA.NZ","MOW.NZ","MRP.NZ","MVN.NZ","NPT.NZ","NPX.NZ","NTL.NZ","NWF.NZ","NZF.NZ","NZO.NZ","NZR.NZ","NZX.NZ","OIC.NZ","PCT.NZ","PEB.NZ","PFI.NZ","PGC.NZ","PGW.NZ","PIL.NZ","POT.NZ","PPG.NZ","PPL.NZ","RAK.NZ","RBC.NZ","RBD.NZ","RNS.NZ","RYM.NZ","SAN.NZ","SCT.NZ","SCY.NZ","SEA.NZ","SEK.NZ","SKC.NZ","SKL.NZ","SKT.NZ","SLG.NZ","SLI.NZ","SML.NZ","SPN.NZ","SPY.NZ","STU.NZ","SUM.NZ","TEN.NZ","THL.NZ","TIL.NZ","TME.NZ","TPW.NZ","TRS.NZ","TTK.NZ","TUA.NZ","TUR.NZ","TWR.NZ","VCT.NZ","VHP.NZ","VIL.NZ","WDT.NZ","WHS.NZ","WYN.NZ","XRO.NZ","ZEL.NZ")

#Download the stock history (for all tickers)
 sdata <- getSymbols(tickers, env = stockData, src = "yahoo", from = startDate, to = endDate)
 stockinf <- stockData$sdata
 head(stockinf)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The retrieved symbols are in `stockData` environment. By default, `getSymbols` will only return the ticker name and save the object in the specified environment.

```
sdata
## [1] "ABA.NZ"


ls(stockData)
## [1] "ABA.NZ"


head(stockData$ABA.NZ)
##            ABA.NZ.Open ABA.NZ.High ABA.NZ.Low ABA.NZ.Close ABA.NZ.Volume ABA.NZ.Adjusted
## 2009-01-01        4.55        4.55       4.55         4.55             0            3.73
## 2009-01-02        4.55        4.55       4.55         4.55             0            3.73
## 2009-01-05        4.52        4.52       4.52         4.52             0            3.70
## 2009-01-06        5.05        5.05       5.05         5.05          9000            4.14
## 2009-01-07        4.66        4.66       4.66         4.66           300            3.82
## 2009-01-08        4.67        4.67       4.67         4.67             0            3.83
```